# How to calculate the cap of a sphere of radius R with Spherical Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I learnt calculus 3 a couple of months ago but I didn’t practice it as much, prioritizing understanding it and applying it in physics. I recently came over a question involving using the volume of the cap. I tried to derive it using spherical but i wasn’t able to. My applications of calculus involve nice and simple concepts so i kind of get rusty on topics like vector calculus, multiple integration (calculus 3 in general). Any tips? i’m thinking of having this period where i solve some calculus questions as to review and consolidate what i learnt.

Comment: See https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/41955983603b4b7d2f98323493903430_MIT18_02SC_pb_47_comb.pdf